# How to display layer of neural network using h20 in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, h2o

is there any way I can display an image or diagram of my neural net using h20 in R. Also, I went through the h20 documentation but couldn't figure out to extract weights from the neural net object.

Answer (score 1):

In `h2o.deeplearning()` set `export_weights_and_biases=T` and then once your model has finished building you can extract the weights with `h2o.weights()`. H2O doesn't provide methods to display a diagram for your neural net.